# Laravel scheduler not working when called from controller

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I have created a console command that (for now) just outputs a log statement.

That command is scheduled every minute.

I have a controller endpoint (located at /scheduler/run) that performs an Artisan::call(); to the artisan schedule:run command.

Locally it works perfectly (laravel valet & nginx), on production (apache) however, nothing happens when hitting that endpoint...
I do get the reply from my controller, but the scheduler is never triggered.

My route:

```
Route::get('/scheduler/run', SchedulerController::class)->name('scheduler');
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class SchedulerController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        Artisan::call('schedule:run');

        return response()->noContent();
    }
}
```

My Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Console\Commands\PingCommand;
use App\Console\Commands\RefreshTwikeyKey;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        PingCommand::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command(PingCommand::class)->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm it should work as far as I'm aware. Just curious, what is your intention of running this inside a controller? Its meant to be single cron command.

Comment: Don't you have any errors in your hosting panel? Sometimes hosting providers have PHP "proc_open" function disabled and then Artisan is not working.

Comment: No errors at the hosting panel. The reason that i created the http endpoint is that i can only add http endpoints as cron entries in that hosting provider. I have done this many times over, never had any issues.

Comment: What is also weird is that running php artisan schedule:run on the cli does work...

Comment: Adding Artisan::call('my:ping'); which is the signature for my ping command, also works...so it appears to be just the call to the scheduler that is not working from a controller